# Why is "void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept;" not defined in gcc 4.9.0?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, c++14

As per the draft C++14 standard 18.2.1.1, the following global function is implicitly defined:

`void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept;`

However, the following code cannot be accepted by gcc 4.9.0 but can be compiled with clang 3.4.

```
int main()
{
    // error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'void*'
    ::operator delete(new int, 1); 
}
```

Is this a defect of gcc 4.9.0?

Comment: Did you specify `-std=c++1y`?

Comment: Yes, I specified the compiler options with -std=c++1y.

Comment: My environment is MinGW64.

Comment: As an aside, I looked at http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3536.html which suggests that `size_t` is the size of the area to delete. It seems unlikely that `new int` would yield a 1 byte allocation.

Comment: "C++14" is only the tentative name of something that doesn't exist yet. There's nothing there to completely support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> gcc 4.9.0 which claims to completely support C++14

gcc 4.9.0 makes no such claims. The `operator delete` definition you're referring to was added as part of the [sized deallocation](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3778.html) proposal, which is [as yet unimplemented](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html) in gcc.

Answer (score 0):

According to OP by [a previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24522518/revisions):

The toolchain is gcc 4.9.0 rather than clang 3.4.